# How to correctly put requirements.txt file into Google App Engine flexible?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tensorflow, requirements.txt

I trying to deploy an app through `PyCharm`.
My app uses `TensorFlow` lib for python and imports it.
I created `requirements.txt` in same folder where is my `yaml` and `py` is stored.
The content of requirements.txt is just a link:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorfl‌​ow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-no‌​ne-linux_x86_64.whl
```

There is `vm:true` is set in `yaml`.

After deploying this project I getting `ImportError: No module named tensorflow` when visiting my app at appspot and looking into errors list.

The link is correct and works fine for bash:

```
Metafalica@DESKTOP-MC1D431:~$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorfl‌​ow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-no‌​ne-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorfl‌​ow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-no‌​ne-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (39.8MB): 97% 39.0MB
...
```

So why VM didn't installed TensorFlow? Maybe I need to do something manually by some command or what? Maybe I need to set some options in PyCharm? I totally new to all this.

Comment: Is the link correct? I copy and paste it and it doesn't work. It looks like the second "tensorflow" in your URL has some sort of non-ASCII second "o" in both places you've written it. Maybe try copying and pasting it again from the website?

Comment: @AllenLavoie - but the same link works fine when used from console. I reviewed the link, but even removing non-ascii symbols doesn't make it work in browser.

Comment: The correct link does work in the browser on my machine; it should just download the .whl file: [working link](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl), [mangled non-ASCII link](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorfl‌​ow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-no‌​ne-linux_x86_64.whl). Probably the console is interpreting the unicode as the standard latin characters, while GAE is interpreting it (like browsers do) as something else.

Comment: @AllenLavoie - This one is `rc2` link. Anyway, sadly, but nothing changed when I switched links in my `requirements.txt`. I still see `ImportError: No module named tensorflow` in errors log for my application.